# How can I create a single-one text with different colors in it in HTML

Tags: html

How can I create a single-line text with different colors in it in HTML? Like inner `div` tags with different `style` attributes in it. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I Googd *"single-one text"* feeling a bit ashamed. I'm not any more. The only result I've found is your question here on SO.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan I mean single-line, sorry

Comment: It's not still clear what you want. What DIV are you talking about? What colors? Text, background? please do your best to explain what you need, what you tried, show some code.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/2ywhgggt/

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan I mean that I need smth like this -- `<div> First text <div style="color:red;"> Second text </div> </div>` but in single line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to separate parts with the same color to the **span** tags with different styles. Span is more suitable than **div** here, because span is only considering line formatting, not the whole block of code.

Otherwise, using pure HTML for styling text is not recommended and it's generally considered to be a very bad practise.

---

### Example:

#### HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Colors</title>
</head>
<body>
    This text will be <span class="g">green</span> and <span class="b">blue</span>.
</body>
</html>
```

#### CSS

```
.g {
    color: green;
}

.b {
    color: blue;
}
```